# Flutter : How to perform a multi filtering on Firebase Database?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a flutter app, using `Firebase Database`. Below is my database structure, just one table there

[image]

Below is my Flutter query for retrieving the data

```
final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('messages');

new Flexible(
    child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
    query: reference,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    reverse: true,
    sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
    //comparing timestamp of messages to check which one would appear first
    itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
           Animation<double> animation, int x) {
           return new ChatMessageListItem(
           messageSnapshot: snapshot,
           animation: animation,);
           }
     ),
    ),
```

Now, my code downloads all the records from the database. But what I want is to download records, where it matches a certain condition. The condition is `senderID=1` and `receiverID=30`.

In case of MySQL, this is how I will write this query.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE senderID="1" AND receiverID="30"
```

How can I do the same in Firebase?

***Note: I know I can download all the records and do a search. But I don't want to download millions of records into a phone and make a performance issue. Also I don't want to download everyones data into everyones phone and make a huge Security hole.***

Comment: I suggest reviewing the documentation on how to [sort and filter queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) with Realtime Database.  You will make two queries, one for each senderID.  The APIs you see in the documentation for JavaScript should map pretty closely to dart.

Comment: @DougStevenson Got your point. You mean I will first have to search for 'senderID' and then from that result set search again for 'receiverID' ?

Comment: Or you can filter the results of one query locally to find matches for the second condition.

Comment: @DougStevenson code sample please?